# get_avatar() is not working in my custom theme

Tags: theme-development, avatar

I have used this code to display author image. It was working in Local By FlyWheel but isn't working on a live site.
It's not working means that it is not producing any HTML.

```
<?php
   $post_id     = get_the_ID();
   $author_ID   = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
   echo get_avatar( $author_ID, 32);
?>
```

Comment: Where did you use it? Where is `$post_id` defined?

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'not working'? Does it produce no HTML, or the wrong HTML, or some other error? Are you definitely getting the correct value of $author_ID?

Comment: 1. I have added the $post_id in above code.
2. It's not working means that it is not producing any HTML.

Comment: On your live site, check to make sure avatars are enabled. It's under Settings » Discussion. If the **Show Avatars** box is unchecked, then [`get_avatar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) will return `false`.

Comment: Thank you Pat J, that was indeed the real problem.